# eloquent laravel relation hasManyThrough

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id')->primary();
            $table->string('name',100);
            $table->string('state',50)->nullable();
            $table->string('country',10);
            $table->float('lot');
            $table->float('lat');
        });

        Schema::create('followed_cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('city_id');
        });
```

And i made that relation in User class:

```
    public function cities()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(City::class,FollowedCity::class);
    }
```

I tried putting this code into Controller and it doesn't work

```
        $id=Auth::user()->id;
        $followedCities = User::with('cities')->findOrFail($id);
```

I'm trying to get details for every city that this user is following. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use Many to Many relation

in `User.php`

```
public function cities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(City::class , 'followed_cities');
}
```

Comment: Watch out, you forgot to drop a comma between the class name and the association table name